# Cursor for spliting t-sql @xml variable on elements level

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, cursor

I need to define some cursor for spliting t-sql @xml variable on elements level into different @xml(s).

for example:

```
<root>
<element id=10/>
<element id=11/>
<element id=12/>
<element id=13/>
</root>
```

so that get the following values inside of tsql cursor:

`<root><element id=10/><element id=11/></root>`

then

`<root><element id=12/><element id=13/></root>`

and so on where n number of elements pro cursor loop.

Comment: Why you want to do this using cursor?

Comment: Because I can split then big xml file into different transactions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you can use the build-in functions for manipulating `XML`. For example, the following statement:

```
DECLARE @XML XML = N'<root><element id="10"/><element id="11"/><element id="12"/><element id="13"/></root>'

SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY T.c) 
       ,T.c.query('.')
FROM @XML.nodes('root/element') T(c)
```

will give you all `elements` preserving the order they have in the `XML` structure:

[image]

Then you can stored this result and build separate smaller `XML` variables.

---

For different elements you can use `*` like this:

```
DECLARE @XML XML = N'<root><element1 id="10"/><element2 id="11"/><element3 id="12"/><element4 id="13"/></root>'

SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY T.c) 
       ,T.c.query('.')
FROM @XML.nodes('root/*') T(c)
```

[image]